# When is the Chern integral given by the norm of the curvature tensor?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, chern-classes

I saw somewhere that for a Kahler manifold that admits a Kahler-Einstein metric the following integral formula is true.

$$\int_M c_2 \wedge \omega^{n-2} = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}\int |Rm|^2 \omega^n$$

It says that this follows from Chern-Weil theory. My question is what is the weakest assumption under which this holds? Does $\omega$ have to be necessarily Kahler-Einstein, or is there some weaker assumption? Some reference for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but take a look at page 5 of "Premières formes de Chern des variétés kählériennes compactes" by Bourguignon, http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=SB_1977-1978__20__1_0. There you find a general formula that comes from Chern-Weil, which simplies in the Kahler-Einstein case. Some references can be found there.

Comment: Sorry, this material is not on my fingertips. Page 5 is short enough to use google translate, and Chern's paper with the original Chern-Weil formula for $c_2$ is definitely in English.